# How do I insert the same row in two tables using a trigger with T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am struggling 2 hours right now. I have `tableoefenen2` and `tableoefenen3`. I want to get the same row in `tableoefenen3` after a new row is inserted into `tableoefenen2`.

This is what I have created in T-SQL:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tbloefenen_Trigger2 
ON tbloefenen2
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tblOefenen3
        SELECT naam, achternaam, datum, uren, id 
        FROM Inserted
END
```

After I am inserting a new row into tableoefenen2 it only selects the columns from inserted..

So I am looking how can I query that the tbloefenen3 will be updated with the new row of tableoefenen2 ?

I can't find the right query.. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Table names that have a pattern with a sequential value appended to them are usually an indication of a schema problem. And don't develop the lazy practice of writing insert statements without any column list - eventually that WILL cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

```
CREATE TRIGGER tbloefenen_Trigger2 
    ON tbloefenen2
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN
    insert into tblOefenen3(naam, achternaam, datum, uren, id)
        select i.naam, i.achternaam, i.datum, i.uren, i.id from inserted i;
    END
```

To check if the records are inserted on the new table fire a select on the new table.

```
select naam, achternaam, datum, uren, id 
from tblOefenen3
where id = <Id that was inserted>
```

If you are still struggling,visit DB fiddle link for complete solution and the tests. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9beddc6c2d16154bbf8237a3a6a15128

Comment: Thank you very much. That did help.
But now i am facing the next problem. I am trying to insert something to tableoefenen2 but it can't insert because it's saying that i have to fill in the ID. But i can't because it's filled automatically by cascade and ID is the primary key.
I want to add name and surename (normally it works because other columns allow nulls and id is filled automatically)

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', dbo.tblOefenen2'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.